# How do I use a historic value as at a particular month when there are no values for the given month?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 SQL Server tables.

`PurchaseOrderReceivingLine` (PORL) is a table that contains every receipt from a purchase order. This has hundreds of entries per month.

`PartyRelationshipScore` (PRS) is a table with a party (supplier) reference number (that is used to join to the PORL table) and a score out of 10 for relationship and price. It also has a `date` field for when the score is updated so we have a history of the updates.

What I want to achieve is a supplier summary for each month. So I would have Supplier #, `TotalValue`, `LateParts` etc. I'm fine with creating the code for that. What I'm struggling with is getting the score for the given month if there are no values for that month.

So, for example I might have a value of 5 on the 1st August. Then it doesn't change until the 1st October when it is increased to 6. 
On the grouping, September will have a TotalValue & a LateParts value but because there are no records in September in the PRS table, it will return a `NULL` value. I need it to get the last value recorded and return that (in this case August's 5). So it will return;

```
Aug 2019 - 5
Sep 2019 - 5
Oct 2019 - 6
```

Thanks in advance.

PORL Table

```
+-------+----------------+-------+-------+
| PORL# |   Date (UK)    | Value | Party |
+-------+----------------+-------+-------+
|     1 | 1/8/2019       |   100 |     6 |
|     2 | 1/8/2019       |   250 |     6 |
|     3 | 1/9/2019       |  1000 |     6 |
|     4 | 1/10/2019      |  2000 |     6 |
+-------+----------------+-------+-------+
```

PRS Table

```
+-------------+------------+-------------------+------------+
| DateChanged (UK) | Party | RelationShipScore | PriceScore |
+-------------+------------+-------------------+------------+
| 1/8/2019         |     6 |                 5 |          5 |
| 1/10/2019        |     6 |                 6 |          7 |
+------------------+-------+-------------------+------------+
```

Preferred outcome

```
+----------+-------+------+------------+-------------------+------------+
| Supplier | Month | Year | TotalValue | RelationshipScore | PriceScore |
+----------+-------+------+------------+-------------------+------------+
|        6 |     8 | 2019 |        350 |                 5 |          5 |
|        6 |     9 | 2019 |       1000 |                 5 |          5 |
|        6 |    10 | 2019 |       2000 |                 6 |          7 |
+----------+-------+------+------------+-------------------+------------+
```

The relationshipscore & pricescore for month 9 are based on it not changing from month 8.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *as text tables* in the question.  Also show your current query.

Comment: The very first step is to create yourself a calendar table at the month level. This is simple a list of months (and years) that you can outer join to to ensure that your query always returns every month.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I will have records for every month from the PORL table. It is the PRS table that wont necessarily have any, in which case it would need to get the value from the month previous.

Comment: At this point it would help if you could post table DDL including unique keys and a sample SQL statement, along with sample input values and desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this helps

```
select Supplier = T.Party
     , Month = DATEPART(MONTH,T.[Date])
     , Year = DATEPART(YEAR,T.[Date])
     , T.TotalValue
     , R.RelationShipScore
     , R.PriceScore
from (  Select P.[Party],P.[Date],[TotalValue] = sum(P.[Value])
        from PurchaseOrderReceivingLine P
        group by P.[Party],P.[Date] ) T
outer apply ( select top 1  RelationShipScore , PriceScore 
              from PartyRelationshipScore
              where Party = T.Party 
              and DateChanged <= T.[Date]
              Order by DateChanged desc ) R
```

Comment: @dimaSUN this works perfectly thank you. Like Nick, I've learned something new today.